# How to define a concept for positive number?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to create a compile-time sum function, and I want it to make sure that all its given arguments are positive:

```
template<typename T>
concept Positive = requires(T t) {
    { /*what should be here?*/ } ;
};

template<Positive... T>
int sum(T... x) {
    return (x + ...);
}
```

But I wasn't able to figure out how to do it...

Comment: Im not sure this is possible as concepts are early compile time. Therefore this could only ever work with const numbers

Comment: Types can be unsigned, but a type can't be "positive". That is a property of a *value*, not a type.

Comment: It would be more annoying than helpful (and more dangerous too) as you would have to ensure that all constants and variable are unsigned... and if you do a cast (on a negative number), then the result would generally be worst that without the unsigned constraint. Thus is is the **wrong tool for the job** as a run-time check would be more appropriate/usuable than a compile-time check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer to your question would be [`std::is_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned).

**However** using unsigned integer types should be avoided. They interact weird with signed types.

So if you use signed integers (as you should) concepts can't help with that because concepts are compile-time checks while the value of an integer is known at runtime. For this you use unit tests and asserts. C++ contracts should have been the tool for this, but unfortunately it has been push back.

> Is there a way to make a compile-time check for positive inputs if
> this function was a constexpr and evaluated at compile time?

Yes. You can throw and if the function is evaluated in a constant expression it will cause a compile error:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <class... Args>
constexpr auto sum(Args... args)
{
    if ((... || (args < 0)))
        throw std::invalid_argument{"error negative number in sum"};
    return (... + args);
}

auto test()
{
    constexpr int r = sum(1, 2, -1); // <-- error here

    return r;
}
```

> In function `auto test()`: in 'constexpr' expansion of `sum<int, int, int>(1, 2, -1)` error: expression '' is not a
> constant expression
>
> ```
> 7 |         throw std::invalid_argument{"error negative number in sum"};
>   |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Comment: I see... Is there a way to make a compile-time check for positive inputs if this function was a constexpr and evaluated at compile time?

Comment: If OP is happy to limit their input types to unsigned integers (it is a _sum_ after all), then constraining it to use `std::is_unsigned` isn't unreasonable at all. Preference for signed or unsigned integers is a code style choice more than it is a universal idiom, and the decision to use or forbid unsigned numbers is a contentious issue, therefore I feel it is out of scope for the question.

Comment: I don't have the link now, but in a cpp talk a full panel of experts including Bjarne expressed this ideea that using unsigned integer types throughout the standard library is a bad decision in hindsight. Unsigned types in C/C++ have a lot of problems because they don't represent numbers, they represent classes of numbers.